# What is the secret password of the rabbit?

Tags: story, password

> Once a talking rabbit came to me and told me, "I will take you to the moon," then it took me near a spaceship.
>
> I was shocked to see it, but I had to enter a 7 digit password to open the door of the spaceship.
>
> When I asked it what the password was, it started to scold me in bad words. "@*$$%&^".
>
> So I started crying. Please help to find the password?

What is the password?

Comment: Question States you had entered password to open the door?

Comment: I still don't get it why this is bad question? This is highest downvote I ever got ..

Comment: I think it is unfair to down vote a question simply , I saw like -2 within 3-4 sec i posted question and nobody can read the entire puzzle within few sec seconds ??? can this be discussed in meta ?

Comment: there are already in meta posts about the recent downvotes. not sure which meta

Comment: If the rabbit didn't specify a keyboard layout then there is no single unambiguous answer to this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 2844576
>  The digits correspond to the symbols on alphanumeric part of the keyboard.

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it...

Comment: not on everyone's keyboard :'(

Answer (score -2):

The solution is:

> * @ *$$%^ (no blank spaces)

because:

> if you edit, you can see that the rabit said: "* @ *$$%^" (with no blank spaces)

Comment: not that........

Comment: it changed, it was different before